# How to overcome Runtime Error 9 when using passed variables in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets()?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing code in Excel VBA, 2007, to copy specific charts and tables into specific Slides and specific Placeholders.  I have made working code to do this, but it is long and hard to read and understand what is happening.  To that end, I decided to write a sub to handle the brunt of the workload and reduce the amount of code I have.  I worked through some syntax errors in passing the parameters, but now I have run into an issue that I cannot quite understand.  I am getting Runtime error 9 in reference to the line of code below.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(oSheet).ChartObjects(oChart).CopyPicture
```

This line of code works just fine in the old program, without the variables having been passed to it.  I tried a couple different ways of attacking the problem based on some information I had, such as enclosing the variable in quotation marks,adding ‘.Value’ to the end of the variable, and I have also switched between ByVal and ByRef in the beginning of the code.  I have also verified that the parameters are beeing passed correctly to Sub CopyChart correctly by stepping through the code and watching the Locals window.  Also, the strings being passed to the parameters are indeed names of sheets and charts in my excel file.  Below is a shortened version of the code I am using.

```
            Private nPlcHolder As Integer
            Private PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
            Private PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
            Private PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
            Private x As Integer
            Private oSheet As String
            Private oChart As String

            Public Sub CopyChart(ByRef x As Integer, ByRef y As Integer, ByRef oSheet As String, ByRef oChart As String)
            'x is slide number(count zero as 1), y as placeholder number
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(oSheet).ChartObjects(oChart).CopyPicture
                PPPres.Slides(x).Select
                With PPPres
                    nPlcHolder = y
                    .Slides(x).Shapes.Placeholders(nPlcHolder).Select msoTrue
                    .Windows(1).View.PasteSpecial (ppPasteMetafilePicture)
                End With
            End Sub

            Sub ChartToPresentation()
                ' Uses Early Binding to the PowerPoint Object Model
                ' Reference existing instance of PowerPoint
                    Set PPApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
                    ' Reference active presentation
                    Set PPPres = PPApp.ActivePresentation
                    PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide

                    Call CopyChart(6, 2, "Chart 3", "Charts")
                    Call CopyChart(7, 2, "Chart 1", "Charts")
                   ' Clean up
                    Set PPSlide = Nothing
                    Set PPPres = Nothing
                    Set PPApp = Nothing
            End Sub
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You declare your variables as 'Private' outside of your sub window. I was not aware that this is possible; have you tried moving those declarations down to being held within the subs that use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the strings being passed to the parameters are indeed names of sheets and charts in my excel file.

Are you sure?

Does a sheet named "Chart 3" have a chart object with the name "Chart".  (When the chart is selected the chart name is shown on the toolbar to the left of the formulabar ).  Charts are normally named "Chart 1", "Chart 2" unless you change them!

Also add a break point on the problem line and in the immediate window check the active workbook!  debug.print Activeworkbook.name

You code looks ok.
h

Comment: Good grief.  Thanks for the extra set of eyes!  I did reverse the Sheet name and Chart name.  The code works fine.